# HTML parsing div.p.ol returns blank in Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-lists

Based on the screenshot below, I am trying to get the "ol" label as the header tag so then I can run a for loop with all the "li" tags beneath it to get the content/addresses of the "aria-label"s.

However, my code returns blank. Anyone know how I can get this "ol" to act as a header? Much appreciated!!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# website
sitemap = 'https://www.walmart.com/store/finder?location=87321&distance=100'
# content of website
sitemap_content = requests.get(sitemap).content
# parsing website
soup = BeautifulSoup(sitemap_content, 'html.parser')
#print(soup)
header_div = soup.div.ol.li
print(header_div)
```

[screenshot of inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIqlF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is stored as Json inside the `<script>` element.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.walmart.com/store/finder?location=02468&distance=100'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#storeFinder').string)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some data to screen:
for store in data['storeFinder']['storeFinderCarousel']['stores']:
    print(store['displayName'])
    print(store['address']['address'])
    print(store['address']['postalCode'], store['address']['city'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Framingham Store
121 Worcester Rd
01701 Framingham
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Walpole Supercenter
550 Providence Hwy
02081 Walpole
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Quincy Store
301 Falls Blvd
02169 Quincy
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Out of curiosity, why does the <script id="storeFinder" type="application/json"> in inspect element only show the details for one store when your code outputs the locations of all the stores?

Comment: @Regression1234 Probably the site manipulates the content of page dynamically through Javascript. Always do `print(soup)` to see, what is the original response from the server.